# Group count values in comma separated field in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a `users` table with a column `product`.

I would like to count how many products are in my table

`Users` table

```
+----------+
| Products |
+----------+
| A        |
| B        |
| A,c      |
| C,B,A    |
| D        |
+----------+
```

i.e. count for A is: 3, count for B is: 2, count for C is: 2, count for D is: 1

Comment: Why don't you normalize the table?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT Products, COUNT(Products)
FROM(
    SELECT 
         Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Products
    FROM  
    (
         SELECT
          CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Products, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS CVS  
        from YourTable
    ) AS A CROSS APPLY CVS.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)x GROUP BY Products
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive queries - step of recursion splits on 2 columns - `l` - that contains entry without comma and `r` - tail of `Products`, after that make `GROUP BY` by `l` column:

```
WITH expandProd as(
    SELECT
        CASE 
            WHEN charindex(',', Products) < 1 THEN Products
            ELSE LEFT(Products, charindex(',', Products)-1)
        END as l, -- the column without comma
        CASE 
            WHEN charindex(',', Products) < 1 THEN NULL
            ELSE RIGHT(Products, LEN(Products) - charindex(',', Products))
        END as r -- the column with tail
     FROM prods 
     UNION ALL --recursive query that enters again to itself
     SELECT 
         CASE 
             WHEN charindex(',', r) < 1 THEN r
             ELSE LEFT(r, charindex(',', r)-1)
         END as l, 
         CASE 
             WHEN charindex(',', r) < 1 THEN NULL
             ELSE RIGHT(r, LEN(r) - charindex(',', r))
         END as r 
     FROM expandProd 
 WHERE r is not null --small optimization
)
SELECT l, COUNT(l) 
    FROM expandProd
    GROUP BY l
```